# Objective C for .NET

Tags: .net, objective-c

Any other package like this 
http://code.google.com/p/oscompiler/downloads/detail?name=OSCv0.1.4.zip&can=2&q=

I'm surprised by the very small size. Do I need to install Gnustep for the headers file ?

Comment: The summary page just says that it requires .NET 4. Are you experiencing a problem? If so can you be more specific?

Comment: Well I have no problem, my question is rather is there any other similar package.

Comment: OK - it's just your comment about Gnustep implied (to me) that you were having problems.

Comment: Can I ask what do you plan to do in objective-C?

Comment: I'm just learning but I prefer windows to mac that's why I was looking for .net :)